# How does openiddict select a signing certificate from multiple certificates

Tags: openiddict

I looked at the kernel code and didn't find anything similar. Perhaps this function is not provided in openiddict. I would like to know this clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a long search, I managed to find an algorithm for selecting a certificate from several.

```
    static int Compare(SecurityKey left, SecurityKey right) => (left, right) switch
    {
        // If the two keys refer to the same instances, return 0.
        (SecurityKey first, SecurityKey second) when ReferenceEquals(first, second) => 0,

        // If one of the keys is a symmetric key, prefer it to the other one.
        (SymmetricSecurityKey, SymmetricSecurityKey) => 0,
        (SymmetricSecurityKey, SecurityKey)          => -1,
        (SecurityKey, SymmetricSecurityKey)          => 1,

        // If one of the keys is backed by a X.509 certificate, don't prefer it if it's not valid yet.
        (X509SecurityKey first, SecurityKey)  when first.Certificate.NotBefore  > DateTime.Now => 1,
        (SecurityKey, X509SecurityKey second) when second.Certificate.NotBefore > DateTime.Now => 1,

        // If the two keys are backed by a X.509 certificate, prefer the one with the furthest expiration date.
        (X509SecurityKey first, X509SecurityKey second) => -first.Certificate.NotAfter.CompareTo(second.Certificate.NotAfter),

        // If one of the keys is backed by a X.509 certificate, prefer the X.509 security key.
        (X509SecurityKey, SecurityKey) => -1,
        (SecurityKey, X509SecurityKey) => 1,

        // If the two keys are not backed by a X.509 certificate, none should be preferred to the other.
        (SecurityKey, SecurityKey) => 0
    };
```

[Link](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/5045461b933d3170cd4f43619fcf51e7614d97a1/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerConfiguration.cs#L271)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.